# How to use Laravel Eloquent ORM to make an or statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to use `Laravel Eloquent ORM` to make an `OR` statement?

I know I can make multiple select like this (AND)

```
Order::where('id', '<', $myid)->where('finance','ok')->get();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Order::where('id', '<', $myid)->orWhere('finance','ok')->get();
```

That gives you the `OR`

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres gives you more details but it's the `orWhere` that is interesting to us here.